# 'make' command not found in docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, containers, apt-get, docker-container

I have a docker image which is running docker host with ubuntu 14.04.

In one of the containers, I am trying to run zookeeper and install librdkafka libraries(pre-requisite library) for kafka to connect to 3rd party software. I need the 'make' command to build my librdkafka libraries inside the container from where I will be running the kafka adapters/connectors.

However, interestingly I am not able to run 'make' command inside the container, it works perfectly on the docker host. When i try using

```
apt-get install make
```

I get the following message which is not making much sense to me:

```
root@svi-esp-service:/# apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
```

Can someone help me to understand why the make is not getting installed in the container and why cant i run it? I am behind time and need this command running in the container..its really annoying.

Just as a heads up, I have following in the list file:

```
root@svi-esp-service:/# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
```

Help really appreciated!

Comment: Your container has internet access? Are you able to install other packages via apt?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Update APT's package lists by running `apt-get update` first:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install make
```

Comment: I had tried that before but I am getting lot of 404's: Please find the pastebin below for the log of errors: 
https://pastebin.com/FM7NMiBx

Comment: start your container with --host=net should solve the issue

Answer (score 13):

```
RUN apt install build-essential -y --no-install-recommends
```

I recommend apt over apt-get
This will not only install 'make' but others as well, likely needed for development.
-y and --no-install-recommends so it won't block build ;)